# Lost my internet after update to Linux mint Victoria 21.2

Tags: linux-mint, networkmanager

I updated my system to new LINUX MINT 21.2 Victoria and it popped some updates after the install.
After updating my internet is not working.
I am connected to wifi and ethernet as shown by Network Manager but internet is not there.
Please someone help
Iwconfig etc outputs are here

```
root@cipher-Inspiron-3537:/home/cipher# rfkill list
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```